# Gravity forms js API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, плагин

Всем привет! взял пример с документации:
Форма на сайте есть, айди полей и формы указаны правильно, подключен скрипт в functions.php
jquery подключен, в консоли браузера ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: gform is not defined

```
<?php
add_action("gform_pre_render", "set_chosen_options");
function set_chosen_options($form){
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        gform.addFilter('gform_chosen_options','set_chosen_options_js');
        //limit how many options may be chosen in a multi-select to 2
        function set_chosen_options_js(options, element){
            //form id = 85, field id = 5
            if (element.attr('id') == 'input_85_5'){
                options.max_selected_options = 2;
            }

            return options;
        }
    </script>

    <?php
    //return the form object from the php hook
    return $form;
}
?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Comment: Всё же написано. Переменная с именем `gform ` нигде не объявлена. Откуда скрипту про неё знать, когда её нет?

Comment: как тогда ее объявить правильно?

Comment: А что такое этот gform? Я так понял, что это какая-то либа. Надо её подключить в скрипте. Как это сделать я не скажу. В пыхе не работал.

Comment: вот пример из доки как юзать, но про инициализацию объекта ничего не сказано https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_chosen_options/

Comment: У вас проблема в том, что вы запускаете свой скрипт раньше, чем запускается некий другой скрипт, что объявляет gform. Какой это скрипт - надо узнать из описания Gravity Forms или посмотреть в браузере, какие скрипты запускает этот плагин.

Comment: Делать надо всё правильно, тогда не будет таких проблем. Скрипты надо запускать в WP с помощью wp_enqueue_script() https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script . Эта функция позволяет задавать зависимости скриптов. Так что ваш скрипт будет запущен после тех, от кого он зависит. И тогда переменная gform будет уже объявлена.

Comment: всем спасибо, разобрался!

Comment: @kir-khitsenko в чем была причина?